Handling Borrow Propagation in AVX-512 Subtraction of 32-bit Chunks
I'm working on a project where I need to subtract large integers split into 32-bit chunks using AVX-512 in C. My current implementation can perform the subtraction, but I'm having trouble handling the borrow propagation correctly across the chunks.
Here are my input arrays and the current implementation:
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Helper function to print AVX-512 vectors for debugging
void print_vector(__m512i vec, const char* label) {
    uint32_t values[16];
    _mm512_store_epi32(values, vec);
    printf("%s: ", label);
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        printf("%u ", values[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

int main() {
    uint32_t chunks1[16] __attribute__((aligned(64))) = {2659411559, 2356142432, 2010672242, 899752273, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    uint32_t chunks2[16] __attribute__((aligned(64))) = {4032685195, 4212306064, 1334305658, 556193450, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
    uint32_t result[16] __attribute__((aligned(64)));

 
    __m512i vec_chunks1 = _mm512_load_epi32(chunks1);
    __m512i vec_chunks2 = _mm512_load_epi32(chunks2);

    __m512i vec_result = _mm512_sub_epi32(vec_chunks1, vec_chunks2);
    
    // Borrow handling code (issue is here)
    __mmask16 borrow_detected = _mm512_cmpgt_epu32_mask(vec_chunks2, vec_chunks1);

    __m512i vec_borrow_mask = _mm512_maskz_set1_epi32(borrow_detected, 1);

    // Adjust the result for borrows
    vec_result = _mm512_sub_epi32(vec_result, vec_borrow_mask);


    _mm512_store_epi32(result, vec_result);

    // Print the results for debugging
    print_vector(vec_chunks1, "chunks1");
    print_vector(vec_chunks2, "chunks2");
    print_vector(vec_result, "result");

    return 0;
}

The problem arises in handling borrows correctly. In my current implementation, the borrows are detected, but I'm not sure how to propagate them properly across the chunks.
Could someone provide guidance or a better approach to handle borrow propagation in this context? Any help would be greatly appreciated!
I used a mask to detect borrows and created a borrow mask with _mm512_maskz_set1_epi32. I then adjusted the subtraction result using this borrow mask. Borrows are detected but not correctly propagated across chunks, leading to incorrect results when a borrow needs to carry over to the next chunk.
Any guidance or improved approach would be greatly appreciated!

SIMD and long integer don't fit together that well, especially if carry/borrow propagates over multiple chunks -- SIMD is beneficial if you have multiple identical but independent calculation. One possible solution is sometimes to use smaller chunks than fit into an integer (e.g., store 52bit chunks in 64bit integers, which would also be beneficial if you have access to AVX512IFMA52 for multiplications). Or you could just detect single carries/borrows and fall back to scalar code if (occasionally) you need to propagate over multiple chunks.

Btw, you don't need to create the temporary vec_borrow_mask. You can directly use _mm512_mask_sub_epi32. But you probably want to shift the borrow mask (the direction depends on the ordering of your chunks -- i.e., most or least significant first).


In my current implementation, the borrows are detected, but I'm not sure how to propagate them properly across the chunks.

This has been solved before, though your situation is a bit simpler since there is no carry into or out of your vector. You need another comparison to check which chunks are zero (which a borrow will propagate through) let's call that mask p, then you can do this:
borrow = p ^ (p + (borrow << 1))

In the addition p + (borrow << 1), borrows go up through ranges of bits that are set in p (which correspond to ranges of zeroes in vec_result), resetting those set bits as they go up, and eventually "land" in a zero, which they turn to 1. XORing with p gives a mask of not only where the borrow lands, but also of where it came through and reset some bits.
You could replace this combo:
__m512i vec_borrow_mask = _mm512_maskz_set1_epi32(borrow_detected, 1);
// Adjust the result for borrows
vec_result = _mm512_sub_epi32(vec_result, vec_borrow_mask);

.. with a masked subtract:
vec_result = _mm512_mask_sub_epi32(vec_result, borrow, vec_result, _mm512_set1_epi32(1));

Or you could use addition instead of subtraction, that way the constant can be created cheaply, without reading it from memory, in one instruction (compilers could use eg vpcmpeqd or vpternlogd to synthesize -1):
vec_result = _mm512_mask_add_epi32(vec_result, borrow, vec_result, _mm512_set1_epi32(-1));

